# SQL Server XML Result

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have two tables `Customer` and `Address`. I want to be able to return the result set like

```
CustomerID   Name  LastName   AddressList
--------------------------------------------------
    1        ABC   DEF        <AddressList><address><line1>XXX</line1></address><address><line1>XXX</line1></address>
```

Basically, create an XML for all linked addresses and return it as a column.

I am using `FOR XML PATH (' ')` on address but I am getting 2 rows back with address as XML in each row. I want only 1 row with both addresses

Here's my sql

```
SELECT 
    c.customerId,
    c.Name,
    c.LastName,
    (SELECT a.* FOR XML PATH(''))
FROM 
    Customer c
JOIN
    Address a ON c.CustomerId = a.CustomerId
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use something like this.

```
SELECT  
      c.customerId,
      c.Name,
      c.LastName,    
      CAST( 
          (SELECT a.* 
           FROM  Address a
           WHERE c.CustomerId = a.CustomerId
           FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('AddressList'))   
           AS xml) as AddressList
FROM   Customer c
group by c.customerId, /*you can ignore group by if you don't have duplicates*/
 c.Name,
 c.LastName;
```